# English translation of Sefer Machaneh Yisrael

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, army-military-war, english, chofetz-chaim

Is there an English translation (preferably online) of the Chofetz Chaim's sefer [Machaneh Yisrael](http://hebrewbooks.org/40438) (a guide for Jewish army conscripts), or other English works on the same topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a translation of *Machane Yisrael* into English published as English-only (the original Hebrew is not included). It's *[Machaneh Yisrael](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?P_ID=5153&strPageHistory=related)* (I mean, that's how they spell the title) and the copyright page reads:

> Authored by
>   Rav Yisrael Meir HaKohen Zt"l
>   The Chofetz Chaim
>
> Translated by
>   Machon MEMEY
>   413 Ashley Ave. • Lakewood, NJ 08701
>   (732) 364-4003
>
> © Copyright 2010
>   Printed in Israel
>
> Published by
>   Machon Sofrim
>   (732) 942-7307

Answer (score 4):

Just came across an older translation - http://www.hebrewbooks.org/22154

Comment: Note that that volume indicates that it's "inspired by and based upon" _Machane Yisrael_ and (further along) explicitly denies being a translation.

Comment: @msh210, thanks for that clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Netzach Yisrael translated by HaRav Yedidya Levy of Congregation Mazal Elul; deals with similar topics.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved if you posted a link to that Sefer. Otherwise I see nothing wrong.